# How to add enum type for value of HTMLInputElement

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, events, enums

How can I inject custom enum type to value of HTMLInputElement?

I searched typescript document but cannot find to do this.

```
enum ValidColor {
  'red',
  'blue',
}

class paintStore {
  wallColor: ValidColor = 'red';

  onPaintClick = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.wallColor = e.target.value // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ValidColor'.ts(2322)
  }
}
```

I tried to make a custom type but failed.

```
interface ColorTarget {
  value: ValidColor;
}

interface MyColor extends HTMLInputElement {
  target: ColorTarget;
}

onPaintClick = (e: React.ChangeEvent<MyColor>) => {
    this.wallColor = e.target.value // it is not working...
  }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

That's because e.target.value could be any string.

You probably want to safeguard that the colour is going to be 'red' or 'blue' some other way.

The simplest way is telling the compiler "I know this colour is going to be red or blue" using the 'as' keyword:

```
enum ValidColor {
  'red',
  'blue',
}

class paintStore {
  wallColor: ValidColor = 'red';

  onPaintClick = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.wallColor = e.target.value as ValidColor;
  }
}
```

A better way is to use user defined type guards (more here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html)

```
enum ValidColor {
  Red = 'red',
  Blue = 'blue'
}

const validColors: string[] = [ValidColor.Red, ValidColor.Blue];

const isValidColor = (inputColor: string): inputColor is ValidColor => {
  return validColors.indexOf(inputColour) !== -1;
};

class paintStore {
  wallColor: ValidColor = 'red';

  onPaintClick = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const maybeColor = e.target.value; // here it's a string

    if (isValidColor(maybeColor)) {
        // inside this block, maybeColor is narrowed to type ValidColor...
        this.wallColor = maybeColor;
    }

    // Decide what to do if it's not a valid color here
  }
}
```

Notice the return type of the function isValidColor - it tells TypeScript how to adjust the type of the return value.